# Django Auth from the POST method, I cannot log in, and it throws invalid credentials

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, backend

I have a django project, when I create a user from empty migration files, I can logged in perfectly. But when I create a user from POST method, I can't logged in and it throwing invalid credentials.

This is my user model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField("Username", max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_password_reset = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, related_name='users')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.deleted_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Hash the password before saving
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        roles_str = "\n".join([str(role) for role in self.roles.all()])
        return f"(username: {self.username}, id: {self.id}, is_active: {self.is_active}, is_password_reset: {self.is_password_reset}, roles:\n{roles_str})"
```

this is my login API view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def login(request):
    username = request.data.get('username')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, context={'request': request})
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        data = {
            'user': serializer.data,
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }
        return Response(data)
    else:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I already tried to debug using raw password without hashing and print out the request from login. It prints out exactly the same as in the database. But it keeps throwing invalid credentials. I think the problem is in the authenticate. but don't know exactly how to fix it.